# Change elements of the columns in dataframe and merge the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have a dataframe df created as,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
     [0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0]],
     columns=['Mon','Tue','Wed'])

df:
    Mon Tue Wed
0   0   1   0
1   1   0   0
2   0   1   0
```

For this dataframe, I want to replace the element '1'- to the respective column name and '0' to be replaced with- "", and finally combine all of them.

1 and 0 can also be characters- 'X' and '-'.

```
Desired Output:
    Day
0   Tue
1   Mon
2   Tue
```

Answer (score 0):

##### without duplicate values (*i.e.* only one `1` per row)

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

*NB. if you have '-'/'X' as values, use `df.eq('X').idxmax(axis=1)`*

output:

```
0    Tue
1    Mon
2    Tue
```

As dataframe:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1).rename('Day').to_frame()
```

output:

```
   Day
0  Tue
1  Mon
2  Tue
```

##### potential duplicates

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
     [0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0]],
     columns=['Mon','Tue','Wed'])

# below use 'value == "X"' if '-'/'X' values
df.melt(var_name='Day', ignore_index=False).query('value == 1')[['Day']]
```

output:

```
   Day
1  Mon
0  Tue
2  Tue
0  Wed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names separated by comma if possible duplicated `1` per rows:

```
df1 = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1].to_frame('Day')
print (df1)
   Day
0  Tue
1  Mon
2  Tue
```

If multiple values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
     [0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0]],
     columns=['Mon','Tue','Wed'])


print (df)
   Mon  Tue  Wed
0    0    1    1
1    1    0    0
2    0    1    0


df1 = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1].to_frame('Day')
print (df1)
       Day
0  Tue,Wed
1      Mon
2      Tue
```